# Regex for checking names with _0, _1 at the end?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regex that captures all names that end with `_0, _1,` like :

```
dog, cart_5, rat_0
```

I tried `/_\d$/.test('abc_0')` but it returns false for 'dog'. I want to find out how to ensure that the  group `(_digit)` **as a whole** is repeated 0 or more times ?

Also, is it possible for me to get the digits after the underscore ? I want to do the last thing via java

Comment: @Daud unclear for me. `I want to write a regex that captures all names that end with _0, _1, ` then why you used `_\d$` ? What's wrong with `_[01]$`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj The rest of the question contradicts that twice

Comment: @keyser: That's why it's unclear.

Comment: SOrry, I meant, _1,_0, etc.. any digit

Comment: @AvinashRaj I mentioned in my question that cart_5 is also to be accepted.

Comment: then try `(?:_\d)*$` or `(?:_\d+)*$`. I already mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @fedorqui i meant that i needed the regex for the first part of the question in any language, but the second part in any java, if possible

Comment: And ask `Also, is it possible for me to get the digits after the underscore ? I want to do the last thing via java` as a separate question.

Comment: Then it is best to split the question in two different ones. Otherwise it creates confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to find out how to ensure that the group (_digit) as a whole is repeated 0 or more times ?

For zero or more `_` any digit.

```
(?:_\d)*$
```

OR

For zero or more `_` any digits.

```
(?:_\d+)*$
```

OR

For zero or more `_` plus 0 or 1.

```
(?:_[01])*$
```

Example:

```
> /(?:_\d)*$/.test('abc_0')
true
> /(?:_\d)*$/.test('dog')
true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\w+_\d+` if you want to find all words that ends with digits. If you want to restrict the match only for 0 or 1 then try `\w+_0|1`.

Here is a sample code in java

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+_\\d+"); //uncomment the code for first case
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+_0|1");
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher("dog, cart_5a, rat_0b");

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
rat_0
```

Comment: OP is writing javascript, as indicated by the `/.../` (and the retagging)

Comment: @keyser I saw it tagged with Java, ok will include javascript. Thanks

Comment: @keyser i meant that I wanted the regex for the first part in js or java, but the last part (if possible) in Java